# mysqli PHP search and filter by two databases/tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to search and filter by two different databases.

```
DATABASE1.table1  |   DATABASE2.table1
id | col2         |   id | ref_col2 | ref_col3
1  | 2            |   1  | thing    | thing
2  | 500          |   2  | other    | other
```

I know you can use the following if its on the same database:

```
$search = explode(" ", mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["search_string"]));
$search_string = " AND (";
for($i=0;$i<count($search);$i++){
    $search_string .= "(t2.ref_col2 LIKE '%".$search[$i]."%' OR t2.ref_col3 LIKE '%".$search[$i]."%') AND ";}
$search_string = substr($search_string,0,strlen($search_string)-4);
$search_string .= ")";  


$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT t1.*, t2.* AS row_count FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN  table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.id>0".$search_string)or die();
```

**My question is:** What if they are on two different databases? is there a specific way to select one database.table results by searching another database.table's list the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if they are on the same server then

```
database1.table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN  database2.table2 AS t2
```

should be fine

Comment: but when launching mysqli_connect(host, user, password, **db**)...wouldnt only be connected to the single db?

Comment: well if you connect to a database using its name then you can omit the dot syntax ... so if you 'connected' to database1 then you could do .... table1 as t1 left join database2.table2 as t2 ... or just preface all tables with the name of the database they are in to avoid confusion

Comment: So I couldn't get this to work before I posted this question, and i thought it was to do with the db, after looking up errors...
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(**t1.***) AS row_count FROM db1.table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN  db2.table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t1.id>0".$search_string)or die();

when counting you cant use t.* you can only use * with no reference to which database :S thanks for your help! check marked for answer!